# Geopandas count roads within certain distance from addresses

Tags: python, pandas, join, gis, geopandas

I have dataset with roads (as shp file) that looks somewhat like this:

| Road_ID | Road_code |
| --- | --- |
| R1 | 1 |
| R2 | 1 |
| R3 | 2 |
| R4 | 3 |

And then some more columns. Then I have an Address dataset that i have also saved as a shp file, with one line for each address and unique Address_id column.

I need to count how many roads are within 150m radius from each address and I am trying to figure out the best way to do that using Geopandas.

So far I have been trying to use spatial join:

1. First create a buffer

   ```
   adr_buffer_150m = addresses.copy()  
   adr_buffer_150m['geometry'] = adr_buffer_150m['geometry'].buffer(150)
   ```
2. Then find all roads within the addresses using a *left join*, but i am not sure if that would be the best way as there can be many addresses close to each road and also many roads close to each address:

   ```
   roads_within_150m = gpd.sjoin(adr_buffer_150m, roads, how='left', op='intersects')
   ```
3. Then count the roads within 150m doing something like this:

   ```
   roads_within_150m.groupby(['Address_id','road_catecory'])['Road_code']
                    .nunique()
                    .reset_index(name='roads_within_150m')
                    .sort_values(by='roads_within_150m', ascending=False)['roads_within_150m']
   ```

This is not working as the join gives me one line for each address. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: In theory this looks fine to me. If there are multiple rows within 150 meters the sjoin should return one row for each road. To debug this, I would try with an "inner" sjoin instead of a "left" sjoin. This returns only the adresses where at least one road was found... This way it is easier to check if the sjoin returns anything at all, and this way you can rule out that your data is e.g. in another crs.